# Asp.net Core Upload File Does not Fire OnPost Code

Tags: asp.net-core

First thing first i want to apology if this topic has been mentioned before, but i looked for 2 days and never find about my problem.

So, I have a IFormFile script, which is does not throw any error (at least a syntax error) but when i am in the Upload Page, i complete my fields (Name,Description and File) and press Upload button, my OnPost code does not Fire at all and my page just referesh.

This is my Razor Page CREATE.CSHTML

```html
@page
@model Appuntamenti.Models.ViewModel.DocumentCreateViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <h4>Upload Single file</h4>
</div>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" runat="server" asp-action="OnPost"  class="mt-3">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description..." />
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label asp-for="Document" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input asp-for="Document" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File..</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control"></button>


    @section  Scripts {
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                    var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                    $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
                });
            });
        </script>
    }
</form>
```

And This is my CREATE.CSHTML.CS page

```html
namespace Appuntamenti.Pages.Documents
{
    
    public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;
       

        public CreateModel(ApplicationDbContext db, IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _db = db;
            _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }


       
        [HttpPost]
        
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync (DocumentCreateViewModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            string uniqueFileName = null;
            if(model.Document != null)
            {
                string uploadsFolder = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "Documents");
                uniqueFileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + model.Document.FileName;
                string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsFolder, uniqueFileName);
                await model.Document.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));

            }

            DocumentModel newDocument = new DocumentModel
            {
                Id = model.Id,
                Name = model.Name,
                Description = model.Description,
                DocumentPath = uniqueFileName
            };
            _db.Add(newDocument);
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index");
        }

    }
}
```

And Those are my 2 Models for the IFormFile

```html
    public class DocumentModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string DocumentPath { get; set; }
    }
    
    
    
        public class DocumentCreateViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        
        public IFormFile Document { get; set; }


        
    }
```

BAsically i tried to put a Breakpoint on the Post Method but it does not fire at all,
I tried to run the Website and inspect the elements,header and network and everything is ok.

After some browsing i read that the Onpost method with the IFormFile rely on the TokenValidation, i tried to ignore the validation and see if something change but nothing. I really dont know what i am doing wrong.

I hope i made my point and problem clear and please if you need more info just let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mixed up Asp.Net Core MVC and Razor Page.

Follow steps below:

1. `CreateModel`

   ```
   public class CreateModel : PageModel
   {
       [BindProperty]
       public DocumentCreateViewModel DocumentCreateViewModel { get; set; }

       //[HttpPost]
       public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
       {
           return RedirectToPage("./Index");
       }
   ```
2. `View`

   ```
   @page
   @model CreateModel
   @{
       ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
       Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
   }

   <div>
       <h4>Upload Single file</h4>
   </div>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div class="form-group row">
           <label asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name..." />
               <span asp-validation-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
           <label asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Description" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <input asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description..." />
               <span asp-validation-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group row">
           <label asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Document" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
               <div class="custom-file">
                   <input asp-for="DocumentCreateViewModel.Document" type="file" class="form-control custom-file-input" />
                   <label class="custom-file-label">Choose File..</label>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control"></button>
       @*<input type="submit" value="Submit" />*@

   </form>

   @section Scripts {
       @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}

       <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $('.custom-file-input').on("change", function () {
                   var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
                   $(this).next('.custom-file-label').html(fileName);
               });
           });
       </script>
   }
   ```

For more information about Razor page, refer [Introduction to Razor Pages in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio)